# How service can bind on 127.0.0.xxx without interface to be present

Tags: linux, localhost

Recently I found that I was able to bind Apache on 127.0.0.73 without 127.0.0.73 to be present.

Only 127.0.0.1 is present as normal.

I also spoke with a friend and he said that is "normal" on Linux and probably on Windows and not works on MacOS, but he has no idea why.

I can do following:

```
[nmmm@zenbook nmmm]$ curl 127.10.0.123
curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.10.0.123 port 80: Connection refused
```

and it shows that whole A class network is available.

**How this works?**

I do not see anything special in `ifconfig` and `ip`, except `lo` interface has no broadcast. Is that the key point?

Answer (score 2):

According to https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost

> IPv4 network standards reserve the entire address block 127.0.0.0/8 (more than 16 million addresses) for loopback purposes.[2](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3330) That means any packet sent to any of those addresses is looped back. The address 127.0.0.1 is the standard address for IPv4 loopback traffic; the rest are not supported by all operating systems. However they can be used to set up multiple server applications on the host, all listening on the same port number. The IPv6 standard assigns only a single address for loopback: ::1.

Or from https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3330

> 

127.0.0.0/8 - This block is assigned for use as the Internet host
loopback address.  A datagram sent by a higher level protocol to an
address anywhere within this block should loop back inside the host.

Even though you can't see anything from `ifconfig` or `ip`, you still can ping all the addresses in that 127.0.0.0/8 block.

Comment: this is very helpful, but does not really answers the question.

Comment: Well, you can bind any IP address to a process. But if you use a random one, you just can not access your service, because your computer will try to connect to the actual IP from internet.

Comment: let me paraphrase the question then. if I do loopback to work with 1.2.3.0 / 255.255.255.0 will this give me 255 local addresses? Is this work because linux 'lo' adapter work like this or there is some hidden setting?